# Make a string clickable, underlined in a TextView

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview, underline

[image]

I want to make the string "this link" underlined and clickable, but I don't know how to achieve that.

XML file:

```
<string name="submitText">Before you submit, please check out &lt;u>this link&lt;/u></string>
```

In my fragment:

```
tvSubmit.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.submitText)));
```

I don't want the whole string to be clickable, only the underlined section. I cannot use a horizontal `LinearLayout` with 2 cells, because on smaller devices the string won't have a continues look, it will be sectioned in 2 cells.

What have I tried:

```
tvSubmit.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
Spannable sp = (Spannable) tvSubmit.getText();
ClickableSpan click = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        showLink();
    }
};
sp.setSpan(click, 0, sp.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

The code above makes the whole string underlined and also the color of the text is changed into light blue.

Comment: You could use `HTML.fromHTML` and insert an `<a href="...">this link</a>` in your string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the problem is that you are setting the span to the whole string (`sp.setSpan(click, 0, sp.length()`). To fix you have to set the clickable  span only on the `this link`. I did the same thing this way:

```
<string name="submitText">Before you submit, please check out %1$s</string>
<string name="this_link">this link</string>
```

in your Activity

```
String thisLink = getString(R.string.thisLink);
String yourString = getString(R.string.submitText, thisLink);
SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(yourString);
spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(click,
                startIndex, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

where startIndex and endIndex are the index of `thisLink` in `yourString`. I separated the two strings because was kind of easier to look for the indexes, especially if you have to deal with translations. To calculate the startIndex you can use `yourString.indexOf(thisLink)`, and endIndex is `startIndex + the length of thisLink`. I'll leave to you the ordinary checks, (negative indexes, and everything else that could cause an `IndexOutBoundException`)

Answer (score 3):

you can define in your strings.xml

```
<string name="submitText">Before you submit, please check out <a href="actual url">this link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 <TextView  
       android:id="@+id/tvSubmit"  
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
       android:autoLink=@String/submitText //link the content of web  
       android:textColorLink="#576586" //change the color of the link  
       android:textColor="#555555" />
```

in activity
//sample

```
String webLinkText = <a href="https://prativas.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/screenshot-mozilla-firefox-private-browsing.png"><img src="https://prativas.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/screenshot-mozilla-firefox-private-browsing.png" alt="Screenshot-Mozilla Firefox (Private Browsing)" width="293" height="254" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-291" /></a>  
 tvSubmit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSubmit);  
 tvSubmit.setText(Html.fromHtml(webLinkText)));
```

check here [for more detailed answer](https://prativas.wordpress.com/category/android/textview-hyperlink-change-color-and-remove-underline/)

Answer (score 2):

In my case i needed to have a localised string with part of it to be clickable.
What i did was to define a string in my resources (one for each locale) with the clickable part underlined, like this:

```
<string name="my_message">Blah blah blah <u>call us</u> blah blah.</string>
```

Then i created an extension to find the underlined text and add clickable span on it, like this:

```
fun CharSequence.makeUnderlineClickable(listener: (index: Int) -> Unit): SpannableString {
    val spannedString = SpannableString(this)
    spannedString.getSpans(0, length, UnderlineSpan::class.java)?.forEachIndexed { index, underlineSpan ->
        val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                listener.invoke(index)
            }

            override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
                ds.isUnderlineText = true
            }
        }
        spannedString.setSpan(
            clickableSpan,
            spannedString.getSpanStart(underlineSpan),
            spannedString.getSpanEnd(underlineSpan),
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
    }
    return spannedString 
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
    textView.text = resources.getText(R.string.my_message).makeUnderlineClickable { index ->
        //handle click here
    }
    textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    textView.highlightColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

Comment: Thanks! Also to make the rest of the textView check the checkbox I added the following
textView.setOnClickListener {
    if (selectionStart == -1 && selectionEnd == -1) {
        onCheckboxClick()
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

just made this function to help me append clickable text to textview :

```
public static SpannableStringBuilder getSpannablableClickFor(CharSequence initialText, ClickableSpan click, String textToAppend) {
    String description = String.format("%s %s", initialText, textToAppend);
    SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(description);
    int start = description.indexOf(textToAppend);
    int end = start + textToAppend.length();
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(click,
            start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(fcs, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return spannableStringBuilder;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### You can try the Kotlin extension function to create text-like and also clickable with an underline.

```
fun TextView.colorSpannableStringWithUnderLineOne(
    prefixString: String,
    postfixString: String,
    callback: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    val spanTxt = SpannableStringBuilder()
    spanTxt.append("$prefixString ")
    spanTxt.append(" $postfixString")
    spanTxt.setSpan(object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            callback(0)
            widget.invalidate()
        }

        override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
            ds.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.highlight)
            ds.isUnderlineText = true
        }
    }, prefixString.length, spanTxt.length, 0)
    this.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    this.setText(spanTxt, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
}
```

`

### How to use this:

```
textViewLink.colorSpannableStringWithUnderLineOne(
                "Normal string",
                "Clickable string",
                callback = {
                    JLog.e("==>","Clicked")
                })
  textViewLink.invalidate()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sp.setSpan(click, 0, sp.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

change value 0 : with position begin link in text, example change value with : 10
if you set 0 it will hyperlink all the text.